# How to edit a Mac mail message scheduled to Send Later

Tags: mail.app, ventura

Using Mail.app macOS 13.1 (Ventura) I can schedule messages to be sent later, which is helpful since my work wants messages sent during business hours but I work on a different time zone than most of the company.  But sometimes I have a message scheduled that needs to have details changed or edited because of something that's happened between when I wrote it and when it's scheduled to be sent.

Q: Is there a way to edit the message after it's been scheduled to be sent but isn't yet sent?  By searching for the message by title etc. I can find the message and I can delete it so it never is sent (and there's no record of it apparently; it doesn't go to my trash folder on my default MS Exchange account).  I can also edit the time of sending so it arrives later or earlier.  But I can't figure out how to change the message itself.  It seems like it should be possible to do so since it's not yet sent.

So far my only work around has been to reply to my own message, reduce the quote level, remove the Re: and "On ... wrote" and pretend that it's the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just another workaround, move it to drafts, edit from there, reschedule it.

Comment: Yes! This solved the problem.  Not as good as if you could edit without rescheduling, but works great.

Answer (score 0):

I find a mailbox named **Send Later** in my Favorites, and I can edit the message in there.
[image: Screenshot from mail]

Comment: I see it there, but I when I open the message it's not editable.

Comment: It's true. No edit option.

Comment: I was able to edit it by opening, using Move To… to move to Drafts. There it is editable, and then I did Send Later again.